# Locate an image and save in JSON type array in Aurelia on submission

Tags: javascript, aurelia

I am working in Aurelia and I have to locate an image and save in JSON type array on submission.

I am unfamiliar to handle images in array because array cannot handle images and we have to convert image to base64 binary but how to do this i do not know. Your help will be helpful for me.

```
<div>
  <div>
    <label>Active</label><br>
    <input type="checkbox">
  </div>
  <div class="mr-3">
    <a class="thumbnail">
      <img src="../../../assets/images/default-user.png" width="100" alt="">
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-8">
    <div class="radio">
      <input type="radio" name="choice" checked> Keep
    </div>
    <div class="radio">
      <input type="radio" name="choice"> Change
    </div>
    <span class="form-group">
      <input type="file" class="mt-3" id="exampleInputFile" files.bind="">
    </span>
    <button class="btn btn-danger" click.delegate="submit()" >Submit</button>
  </div>
```

Array Format

```
this.list = {
      "a_Rows": [
        {
          "pkiCustomerID": "1",
          "simage": "",

        },
```

Comment: Will you copy the images from assets/images folder to your dist folder?

Comment: I will pick from local memory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using HTML5 Canvas (the example code is in Typescript):

```
<input type="file" ... files.bind="selectedFiles" change.delegate="inputChange()">
```

In template JavaScript:

```
export class MyTemplate {
    selectedFiles!:FileList;

    inputChange() {
        let image = new Image();

        image.onload = function () {
            let elem = this as HTMLImageElement;

            let canvas = <HTMLCanvasElement> document.createElement('canvas');

            canvas.width = elem.naturalWidth;
            canvas.height = elem.naturalHeight;

            let context = <CanvasRenderingContext2D> canvas.getContext('2d');

            context.drawImage(elem, 0, 0);

            let stringImg = canvas.toDataURL('image/png').replace(/^data:image\/(png|jpg);base64,/, '');
        };

        let file = this.selectedFiles.item(0);
        if (file !== null)
            image.src = URL.createObjectURL(file);
    }
}
```

`stringImg` is the result you are looking for.

**UPDATE**:

An example for putting the result back to `list`:

```
export class MyTemplate {
    private stringImg: string = '';    // <------ ADDED
    private list: any;                 // <------ ADDED
    selectedFiles!:FileList;

    inputChange() {
        let image = new Image();

        let _this = this;              // <------ ADDED
        image.onload = function () {
            let elem = this as HTMLImageElement;

            let canvas = <HTMLCanvasElement> document.createElement('canvas');

            canvas.width = elem.naturalWidth;
            canvas.height = elem.naturalHeight;

            let context = <CanvasRenderingContext2D> canvas.getContext('2d');

            context.drawImage(elem, 0, 0);

            _this.stringImg = canvas.toDataURL('image/png').replace(/^data:image\/(png|jpg);base64,/, ''); // <------ MODIFIED
        };                   

        let file = this.selectedFiles.item(0);
        if (file !== null)
            image.src = URL.createObjectURL(file);
    }

    submit() {                         // <------ ADDED
        this.list = {
            "a_Rows": [
                {
                    "pkiCustomerID": "1",
                    "simage": this.stringImg,
                },
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: How i can save this base64 string in my array as i mention in code ?and on submission will it convert back to image ?

Comment: See UPDATE above for storing the image to `list`. Yes, the string can be converted back to an image.

Comment: when the form will be submitted then  image will be show on view or need to create method to decrypt string ?

Comment: You may assign the string directly to `img` `src` attribute. See an example [here](https://css-tricks.com/data-uris/)